# Creating and Sharing Pivot Tables using R

Tags: r, excel, pivot-table

I have a regular task - it involves producing a series of pivot tables for a client using Excel. The underlying data comes from an R data frame. Because this data frame contains more than 1M rows, I can't dump it into Excel because of its row limit. Instead I write it to an MS Access DB and then within Excel I point the pivot tables at the Access DB.

Well...this is slow, clumsy, an easy way for errors to creep in, and uses up huge amounts of storage space. I don't like it at all. I'd like to do it better, ie:

(a) find a way (if there is one) to point an Excel pivot table directly at the R data (perhaps via a .RDS file or something like that) OR

(b) cut out Excel altogether and create some kind of pivot table object directly in R which I could then somehow send to my client for him to play with - but for this object to be "dynamic" (in the way that an Excel pivot table is) ie so that the client can drag and drop to select rows, columns, filters, etc. from the list of fields in the table.

Grateful for any suggestions of how best to do this...there seem to be (from doing a bit of Googling) various ways to do pivot table stuff in R, but I'm unsure if any of them fit the bill.

Thank you.

Comment: When you send the file to your client do you also send the Access DB?

Comment: I do, yes. Horrible!

Comment: Honestly, sounds like you should be using a different tool - ie PowerBI/Tableau/MicroStrategy. PowerBI desktop is free and so is MicroStrategy, then send the file over and they can slice and dice to their hearts content.